# How can I set transaction isolation level per session using Play, Hibernate and MySql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, playframework, isolation-level

It can be useful to have repeatable read for some types of web requests, while others are easiest to implement with read committed. How can I specify which isolation level to use per Http request or per session or per transaction?

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate has a implementation of database transactions,as default is JDBC Transaction(the other is JTA).

maybe this will for a help [hibernate docs-transactions and concurrency](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html)

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the answer here in case the link ever changes.